# PHP/HTML form upload multiple images

Tags: php

I have this in my form:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

then this PHP on the action page for the form:

```
$files = array();
$fdata = $_FILES["images"];
if(is_array($fdata["name"]))
{
    //This is the problem
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i)
    {
        $files[] = array(
        'name' => $fdata['name'][$i],
        'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
        );
    }
}
else
{
    $files[] = $fdata;
}

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    move_uploaded_file ( "$pic1_name","$image1") or die("image 1 did not copy<br>");
}
```

but i know i have the `move_uploaded_file` line wrong. what do i need to put in here instead?

UPDATE:

my latest code is as follows:

```
$files = array();
    $fdata = $_FILES["images"];
    if(is_array($fdata["name"]))
    {
        //This is the problem
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i)
        {
            $files[] = array(
            'name' => $fdata['name'][$i],
            'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $files[] = $fdata;
    }

    foreach($_FILES['images'] as $file)
    {
        echo $file['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/img/project-gallery/test');
    }
```

Comment: move_uploaded_file ("$_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];","location")

Comment: why not just do a loop on the $_FILES array? `foreach($_FILES['images'] AS $file){ move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], 'path-to-upload-dir/new-filename.ext'); }`

Comment: i have just tried foreach($_FILES['images'] as $file)
 {
  move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], '../img/project-gallery/'.$file.'');
 }

Comment: then i got the error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: First, inspect(`var_dump`) `$_FILES`. If empty, you forgot to set the proper encoding on your form. Secondly, `$pic1_name` & `$image1` make no sense, did you mean `move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],'/some/path/to/'.$file['name']);`?

Comment: does your form have enctype="multipart/form-data" in the attributes?

Comment: yes it does now - im not getting the error but the file(s) are not uploading. no error message and the folder is fully writeable

Comment: array(1) { ["images"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(38) "Screen Shot 2013-10-10 at 20.11.35.png" [1]=> string(38) "Screen Shot 2013-10-10 at 20.11.52.png" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "image/png" [1]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpRfci9I" [1]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpaGzKuw" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(42097) [1]=> int(313868) } } }

Comment: thats var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: Are you using **FULL** paths for the destination of the files?

Comment: i have tried $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/img/project-gallery/ and ../img/project-gallery/

Comment: when i echo $file["temp_name"] in the foreach loop nothing displays

Comment: it's $file['tmp_name']

Comment: changed to tmp_name and still displaying nothing

Comment: post your full updated code. It's hard to know where you are now. update your answer. don't post code as comment

Comment: Let's start here - you are naming every file in the loop as "test" with no extension. Is test a directory or are you trying to name the files that way deliberately?

Comment: i names them that just to see if they were uploading but $file wasnt giving each one a name

Comment: Is it echoing the tmp_name in the loop? echo $file['tmp_name']; - by the way, you can remove everything above the foreach loop for now

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this...of course add in some validation to make sure users are uploading only file-types which you expect

```
    $currentDate = microtime();

    $storeFolder = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/yourSavePath/";
    $fileNames = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value) {

        if (!empty($_FILES['images'])) {

            //tempfile is the file which has actually been stored on your server
            $tempFile = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];

            //prepend the time so to make filenames unique...the filename here is the one the user sees and the temp filename above is one generated by the server

            $targetFile1 = $currentDate . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];

            //get rid of spaces in the name since they can cause issues
            $targetFile1 = str_replace(' ', '_', $targetFile1);

            $res = move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $storeFolder . $targetFile1);
            $fileNames[] = $targetFile1;
        }
    }
```